# Please reference ID: RGDEAVFI. Error: Faraday::ClientError. Message: INVALID_TYPE: select id from cvcs__c where name = 'xbc1' and ^ ERROR at

Tags: trailhead

I'm taking A TrailHead from link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/secdev_injection_vulnerabilities/units/secdev_inject_cross_site_scripting. When I clik on challenge button, I see below error.

```
There was an unhandled exception. Please reference ID: RGDEAVFI. Error: Faraday::ClientError. Message: INVALID_TYPE: select id from cvcs__c where name = 'xbc1' and ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:16 sObject type 'cvcs__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

[image]

What I tried:

[image]

Comment: Kinda har to help without seeing your code. Or should the have been an edit to: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178198/unable-to-complete-the-understand-soql-injection-trailhead-challenge

Comment: Have you found any solution over this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty dead at this point but if anyone comes across it now just make sure that you have connected to the new (Kingdom)developer org you created in your trailhead. This is not done by default so just make sure you are confirming against the correct org.